# VS 2012 Syntax highlighting

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2012, highlighting

I have 2 computers running VS 2012 pro, and neither of them are showing any of the highlighting or coloring for the XML based files like I had for VS2010.

The only express edition tool I have installed is SQL 2012, so I don't believe that is the problem.

WebMatrix 1 and 2 have never been installed on one of the computers.

I am pretty much at a loss here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed.
I had to reset the environment more than once. Each time resulted in another part of VS breaking when I launched it. Eventually, I had reset it enough times that it is all working now.

Used "devenv /resetuserdata" to reset VS for the fix.

Comment: That worked for me. I was having problems with syntax highlighting for Javascript not working at all and the Dark theme having incorrect text colors.