# VS 2012 not highlighting Javascript code syntax errors

Tags: html, visual-studio-2012

I'm a beginner to JavaScript and I am learning the fundamentals at the moment.

I have used visual studio before for code such as C# and VB and have a decent understand of how it highlights errors etc and shows build errors and what not.

Here is a small bit of code I've written in VS2012 in a HTML 5 file and the issue I have is it has 2 very obvious syntax errors however it does not highlight them and the page is allowed to run in both Firefox/Internet Explorer. The page obviously doesn't work and had I not known this syntax is wrong I wouldn't have been able to diagnose it.

http://pastebin.com/LX4L7YiD

Now I have looked at this topic : [VS 2012 Syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370477/vs-2012-syntax-highlighting)

I can't seem to make out from the above topic what exagtly I need to do to try that fix or even if that fix is relevant to my issue. The poster talks about what he's done but I don't understand how or what he's done.

Comment: Could you please specify where exactly you expect to see an error, it would expedite the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't actually have any syntax errors.

Semicolons are optional, and variables do not need to be declared.

If you want to get errors for those, install [Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com) and turn on [JSHint](http://jshint.com).
(and add `"use strict";` to your code)

Comment: Could you possible give me a syntax error that I could create in the above code just so that I can test it. @SLaks

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I wrote some invalid code and it surely does highlight up etc. My bad, I was convinced that the above was a syntax error. Thanks :) ( I would upvote the answer but it requires me to have 15 points :( )